# Examples of modular forms of irrational or complex weights

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, modular-function

I think that it is possible to define modular forms of complex weight. But I have never seen modular forms of irrational weight, much less of complex (unreal) weight.

If you know any examples of modular forms of irrational or complex weights, please tell me.

Comment: As far as I know (and I know very little), whilst modular forms of half-integer weight are common, modular forms of other weights are not studied. The second you no longer have integral weight, you immediately run into problems with branch cuts (since $(cz+d)^k$ is otherwise not well defined), and things go wrong topologically as a result. For example, the upper half plane $\mathbb H\cong \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)/\mathrm{SO}_2(\mathbb R)$, and modular forms of integral weight can be viewed naturally as functions of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ which obey certain invariance properties under...

Comment: ... the action of $\mathrm{SO}_2(\mathbb R)$. This breaks down for modular forms of half-integral weight - the forms cannot be lifted to functions of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$, and you are forced to consider double covers of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$, the so-called metaplectic groups. With irrational weights, you wouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. If I have a chance someday, I would like to study modular forms of irrational weights.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52996